# CSS style doesn't affect the paragraph in PHP

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph in my PHP code and it doesn't get effected by my CSS style and I have no clue why... I'm not experienced with PHP so I can't see why this doesn't work, it'd be great if someone could take their time and answer me.. Code:

```
<html>
<style>
    h1 {
        font-family:"Arial";
        padding: 5px;
        color: #1e90ff;
    }
    p {
        font-family:"Arial";
        padding-left: 15px;
        color: #000;
    }
    span {
        font-family:"Arial";
        padding: 15px;
        color: #000;
    }
    #contentwrapper {
        width: 750px;
        border: 2px solid #666666;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #808080;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<div id="contentwrapper">
<?php

//connect
I REMOVED THE CONNECTION INFO

//query the db
$getnews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page_index") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnews))

{
//get data
$title = $row['title'];
$header = $row['header'];
$content= $row['content'];
echo "
<title>$title</title>
";
echo "
<center><h1>$header</h1></center>
";
echo "
<p>$content</p><br><br>
";
}
?>
</div>
</html>
```

I know I could just use spans, but there's a reason I want to use the p tag. Thanks!

Comment: install firebug and see what's happening.

Comment: In the end it has nothing to do with PHP: After your PHP is done being parsed, you're left with plain HTML, and that is send to your browser. The resulting plain HTML is the only thing your browser sees, and THAT code is the one where your CSS doens't work like you expect. Try checking out the final code instead of worrying about php.

Comment: This is a plain HTML problem, nothing to do with php [being your markup so essential]. By the way, `<center>` tag is deprecated, and `<br>` shouldn't be used for presentation purposes.

Comment: It looks OK to me, but **the title tag is not for HTML content**. It's for setting the text that appears in the titlebar of the browser. Which styles exactly aren't working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just construct a template for the web page without the PHP stuff - Just raw HTML
2. Put CSS into another file. Just include it. Add that the 1. and ensure it is what it should look like.
3. Modify 1 to add the stuff from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML looks incomplete.

Try adding a `<head>` tag after your `<html>` tag.  Then close the `</head>` tag after the `<title>` tag.

Before the content create a `<body>` tag and close the `</body>` tag before the final `</html>` tag.

Comment: Needs more tag... /just sayin :P

Comment: I was implying that - just suggesting a good route to chose in the development of a web page

Answer (score 0):

Save this contents as test.html and check whether it's your expected output or not? If not modify your css accordingly and paste back css to your php. Head and body tags added.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    h1 {
        font-family:"Arial";
        padding: 5px;
        color: #1e90ff;
    }
    p {
        font-family:"Arial";
        padding-left: 15px;
        color: #000;
    }
    span {
        font-family:"Arial";
        padding: 15px;
        color: #000;
    }
    #contentwrapper {
        width: 750px;
        border: 2px solid #666666;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #808080;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contentwrapper">
<title>title</title>
<center><h1>header</h1></center>
<p>paragraph</p><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```